# Azure mobiles services facebook/provider Oauth in NodeJs sever side

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth

When I test OAuth login,I see the log from developer console side as below

PID[4196] Information Login completed for 'Username'. Provider: 'facebook'.

PID[4196] Information Sending response: 200.77 OK

And my question is

How/Where could I add the function after login done, I have try add function in the azure-mobiles-app module all day, but it's not work.

Does anyone have the experience of that, thanks
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is called callback function.

Something like that.

```
function insertValue(id, obj, cb) {
   mssql.query("..., {
   success: function (operationresult) {...} } ); }
```

Comment: I can't find where to add callback in azure-mobiles-app  modules.

Comment: It's seems that fb didn't redirect callback url(./auth/facebook/callback) when user login.Not the code problem.                                                                     Thanks your reply.